# Call new request only if response of previous request returns from server

Tags: android

I need to receive a status from the server every 5 seconds. I am doing this using AsyncTask.

For every 5 seconds request I use

```
myListTimer = new Timer();
    myListTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    updateMyList();

                }
            });

        }

    }, 0, 5000);
```

Here updateMyList method call AsyncTask and It works fine. But sometime due to network issue I did not got response within 5 sec, and timer again request for new response. So what I want is it will request only if previous response returns from server. If previous request response is not got then it will not request for new response.

Comment: [**May be this**](http://nobalg.tumblr.com/post/98543748225/android-asynctasks-one-after-the-other)

Comment: do save the last response and then write a condition if fails load the previous response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean receivedResponse = false;

myListTimer = new Timer();
    myListTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!receivedResponse) {
                        updateMyList();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }, 0, 5000);
```

Set `receivedResponse` to true in the code that gets called when the response is received.
Set it back to false when you are ready for the next request.